# How to install LLVM-14 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, clang, llvm, rust

I have installed LLVM-14 on Ubuntu manually. Everything seems to work fine except `ld` during the compilation of `cargo-bpf` in Rust cargo.

```
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLLVM-14
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `cargo-bpf` (bin "cargo-bpf") due to previous error
```

Output of `llvm-config --version`

```
root@ip-172-31-0-42:/opt/llvm/cs-fw# llvm-config --version
14.0.0
```

LLVM path: `/opt/llvm/clang+llvm-14.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04`